# submitting form and saving data in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In my wordpress theme, i created a simple page template and place the following simple form to add field in table `ps_custom_cat` which contains only `id` and `name` fields, `id` is auto increment

```
<form name="save_decision" method="get" action="/dal/add_decision_cat.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                category name
            </th>
            <td>
                <input name="name">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

The previous form will save data to table `ps_custom_cat`

The file which will contain the saving actions is (wp-content/themes/mytheme/dal/save_decision.php) in my theme

```
<?php
     $wpdb->insert('ps_custom_cat', array('name' => $_GET['name']));
?>
```

after submitting the for wordpress redirects me to 404 page without saving data, I'm sure the problem in the path of the form, how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function `<?php get_template_part( 'form', 'submit' ); ?>`.

Your file name should be form-submit.php. put this file inside the theme folder.

For Ex.  wp-content/themes/twentytenchild/form-submit.php

And other solution is

Create one page from admin side and select your template where you put your logic.And give action to that page.

Comment: none of them worked with me, but i need to focus on the first method (point to php file directly without new page)

Comment: can you please elaborate your problem. Please provide complete description of the issue you are facing.

Comment: I rewrite the question, you can check it now

Comment: First of all give proper name of file.  Ex, save-decision.php. Your action should look like this <?php get_template_part( 'dal/save', 'decision' ); ?>

Comment: In this file just put your logic nothing else.

Comment: Still not working, can you point to a good tutorial on the same case